# Android upload to network drive(samba share) performance issue

Tags: android, image-uploading, smb, jcifs

i have a problem when I upload a picture of `100kb` to samba share with JCIFS from my tablet, it takes about 10-20 minutes (before I changed my buffer from `1024 to 20971520` it took almost 6 hours) but it does not give any effect anymore to increase it

it is not the connection issue as i had tested it with `ES File` where it Uploaded my picture immediately

```
private class MyCopy extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    String z = "";
    String username = "", password = "", servername = "", filestocopy = "";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {   
            username = edtusername.getText().toString();
            password = edtpassword.getText().toString();
            servername = "smb://" + edtservername.getText().toString();
            filestocopy = editdir.getText().toString();
        }

       protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
   //         String buffer;
  //          buffer = setingPreferences.getString("buffer", "");
            File file = new File(filestocopy);
            String filename = file.getName();

            NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth1 = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(
                    servername, username, password);

            try {

                SmbFile sfile = new SmbFile(servername + "/" + filename, auth1);
                if (!sfile.exists())
                    sfile.createNewFile();
                sfile.connect();

                InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);

                SmbFileOutputStream sfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(sfile);

                byte[] buf = new byte[20971520]; //(parseInt(buffer))
                int len;
                while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0){
                    sfos.write(buf, 0, len);

                }
                in.close();
                sfos.close();

                z = "File copied successfully";
            } catch (Exception ex) {

                z = z + " " + ex.getMessage().toString();
            }

            return z;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to use JCIFS in a J2SE environment to check if it is an Android issue or may be JCIFS is simply the problem? This library seems to be pretty old (last real update 2011)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buffer size shouldn't make a noticeable difference, but it definitely shouldn't be 20M. Use something like 4k instead.

Are you sure it's the actual file transfer that is taking so long? There's no reason 100k should take more than a few seconds at the most. Have you tried putting log statements between each step, including before and after the authentication calls, `createNewFile()`, and `connect()` to check if those are the bottleneck?

Also, I believe you should be copying bytes while the read length is `>= 0` instead of strictly `> 0`, since -1 signals the end of the stream, not 0.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

`new SmbFile("username:password@server/")`

instead of using NTLM? It can also be a DNS issue, so do try

`jcifs.Config.setProperty("resolveOrder", "DNS");`

If neither works, you might want to try `BufferedOutputStream` with your `SmbFileOutputStream`.

Comment: the `new SmbFile("username:password@server/")` giving account currently disabled
`jcifs.Config.setProperty("resolveOrder", "DNS");` didn't fixed it either
how to use the BufferedOutputStream with SmbFileOutputStream as it cannot be applied here `SmbFileOutputStream sfos = new BufferedOutputStream(sfile);`  and is incompatible here `BufferedOutputStream sfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(sfile);`